# Uploading images on Google Drive from IOS Application in Specific Folder provided from the User

Tags: ios, iphone, google-drive-api

I am working with an iOS application in which i have to upload images on Google Drive from my IOS Application.
I am working with the below code,but not getting my image insert in the specific folder.

```
- (void)uploadPhoto:(UIImage*)image
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"'Quickstart Uploaded File ('EEEE MMMM d, YYYY h:mm a, zzz')"];

    GTLDriveFile *file = [GTLDriveFile object];
    file.title = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    file.descriptionProperty = @"Uploaded from the Google Drive iOS Quickstart";
    file.mimeType = @"image/png";

    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation((UIImage *)image);
    GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:data MIMEType:file.mimeType];
   GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:file
                                                       uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
    GTLDriveParentReference *parentReference = [GTLDriveParentReference object];
    // parentReference.identifier = @"root";
  parentReference.identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"root%@",albumNAME];

  file.parents = @[parentReference];


    UIAlertView *waitIndicator = [self showWaitIndicator:@"Uploading to Google Drive"];

    [self.driveService executeQuery:query
                  completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                      GTLDriveFile *insertedFile, NSError *error) {
                      [waitIndicator dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
                      if (error == nil)
                      {
                          NSLog(@"File ID: %@", insertedFile.identifier);
                          [self showAlert:@"Google Drive" message:@"File saved!"];
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
                          [self showAlert:@"Google Drive" message:@"Sorry, an error occurred!"];
                      }
                  }];

     }
```

albumNAME is the name of specific folder in which i have to insert the image on google drive.
Please help me out from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

GTLDriveParentReference.identifier should be the ID of the folder, not it's name. You must first find or create the folder, then use the ID of that folder here.

Comment: GTLDriveParentReference.identifier is the id,,but i am unable to upload images??

Comment: In your code you seem to be using albumNAME. That's an ID?